# I would like to make my code ask for new number every time it finishe's running

Tags: c

I made a program to identify if a number is an Armstrong number , it ask for a number in the start and then it checks if it's an Armstrong number, but i would like if my program can ask again for a new number to check after finishing .

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int numDgt, number, rem, mul = 1, cnt, result = 0;

    printf("Enter a number : ");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    int n = number;
    numDgt = 0;
    while (n != 0)
    {
        n = n / 10;
        numDgt++;
    }
    cnt = numDgt;
    n = number;

    while (n != 0)
    {
        rem = n % 10;
        while (cnt != 0)
        {
            mul = mul * rem;
            cnt--;
        }
        result = result + mul;
        cnt = numDgt;
        n = n / 10;
        mul = 1;
    }

    if (result == number)
    {
        printf("%d is an Armstrong number.", number);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d is not an Armstrong number.", number);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Put the whole thing in a loop and exit the loop if the user enters 0.

Comment: rename your `main` as something else (maybe `secondary`?) then just do `int main(void) { for (;;) { secondary(); } }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run a program continuously, we use a loop.  Please note the addition of the do - while() loop in this code, and its placement.  I have also added a user query (near end of loop) so the user can be prompted and decide to quit or continue.  It's best to prompt like this even if the coder is the only user, so you don't have to remember what values to enter for which program behavior:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int n, numDgt, number, rem, mul = 1, cnt, result = 0, done = 0;

   do{   /* ADDED: Begin do-while() loop */

        printf("Enter a number: ");
        scanf("%d", &number);

        result = 0; /* Added to fix bug per new comment from OP */
        n = number;
        numDgt = 0;
        while (n != 0)
        {
            n = n / 10;
            numDgt++;
        }
        cnt = numDgt;
        n = number;

        while (n != 0)
        {
            rem = n % 10;
            while (cnt != 0)
            {
                mul = mul * rem;
                cnt--;
            }
            result = result + mul;
            cnt = numDgt;
            n = n / 10;
            mul = 1;
        }

        if (result == number)
        {
            printf("%d is an Armstrong number.\n", number);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d is not an Armstrong number.\n", number);
        }
         /* ADDED: query user to continue program or quit */
         printf("Run again? Enter zero to continue, any other number to quit: ");
         scanf("%d", &done);

    }while(!done);   /* ADDED: End do-while() loop */

    printf("\nGood-bye\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you, the program is now running again but I noticed that after repeating the code a second time with the same number the program kind of of breaks and stops giving the right answer as you can see here :                                                                                      Enter a number: 371
371 is an Armstrong number.
Run again? Enter zero to continue, any other number to quit: 0
Enter a number: 371
371 is not an Armstrong number.
Run again? Enter zero to continue, any other number to quit:

Comment: @AmineDELTA -- very welcome.  I'm checking into this new problem on my side, running your code.  Will get back to you ASAP.

Comment: Hi @AmineDELTA -- please see code update where i placed "result = 0" inside the loop.  This fixed the bug on my side, pls let me know if it does for you too...

Comment: it's working thank you very much!

Comment: @AmineDELTA - very welcome and thank you for coming back to select my answer.  Really nice when people take the time to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Examine your code. What does it do inside the single function `main()`?

1. Declare 6 variables whose purpose is not known (some not initialised!)
2. Prompt and accept an input value (unchecked)
3. Tally the number of digits in the value
4. Calculate a new value with nested loops
5. Evaluate the result, printing some output

That's doing too many different things inside one function!

---

Consider instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> // for strtol()

// Get user's value to test
int getVal( char *prompt ) {
    char buf[100], *p = buf;
    int n = -1;

    do {
        printf( prompt );
        fgets( buf, sizeof buf, stdin );
        n = strtol( buf, &p, 10 );
    } while( p == buf || n < 0 ); // only +ve numbers

    return n;
}

// Count digits of 'n'
int cntDigits( int n ) {
    int cnt = 0;

    for( ; n != 0; n /= 10 )
        cnt++;

    return cnt;
}

// Test for Armstrong-ness
int isArmstrong( int n ) {
    int armPoss = n;
    int nDgt = cntDigits( n );

    for( ; n; n /= 10 ) {
        int lowDgtVal = n % 10;
        int prod = 1;

        for( int i = nDgt; i--; )
            prod *= lowDgtVal;

        armPoss -= prod; // down, not up
    }

    return armPoss == 0;
}

int main( void ) {
    int n = getVal( "Enter a number : " );
    char *eval = isArmstrong( n ) ? "is" : "is not";
    printf( "%d %s an Armstrong number.", n, eval );

    return 0;
}
```

By *offloading* work to supporting functions that perform their tasks, `main()` becomes trivial.

Then, all that's needed to fulfill the OP's request is a tweak of `main()`:

```
int main( void ) {
    int n;

    while( ( n = getVal( "Enter number (0 to quit): " ) ) != 0 ) {
        char *eval = isArmstrong( n ) ? "is" : "is not";
        printf("%d %s an Armstrong number.\n\n", n, eval );
    }

    return 0;
}
```